# ReactJS - how to setup login pattern?

Tags: javascript, authentication, reactjs, authorization

I'm sorry if this question is a bit vague, but I'm tackling this problem for the first time and any pointer would be useful.

I am building a web app using ReactJS and I need a login system - first page with two fields username / password and submit button. The server returns a token (`1234`) and this needs to be used in an auth header (`Authorization: Bearer 1234`) in order to access the protected area.

How should I handle the login and make the browser update itself with the new content available after login?

Comment: You'll need to add some more info what kind of authentication you're planning to implement. If you're not sure about that, you'll need to research your options. There are many posts about that on SO and other resources. Maybe this is helpful as well to give some first insight: https://auth0.com/blog/2015/04/09/adding-authentication-to-your-react-flux-app/

Comment: Two good reads: doing it with [React-Router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/master/examples/auth-flow) and [react + flux login ( even has an OAuth example)](https://auth0.com/blog/2015/04/09/adding-authentication-to-your-react-flux-app/)

Comment: Thanks for your comments and links. I edited my question with more details about the authentication.

Answer (score 1):

As the others have pointed out, it is a good idea to use React-Router.

I think you can use pattern like this: You get user inputs and send them via AJAX (with JQuery, Superagent, whatever you want). If the input is valid and user authenticated, the server sends back token with some user info, which can include his roles or permissions. Based on these received data, you can use React-Router to render other component, e.g. welcome page (by calling replaceState on React-Router history object - in flux action for example).

Additionally, you should save this token in a cookie or into a session/local storage (in order to be able to use it on every subsequent request), and the user info could be stored in a Flux store. After saving this user the store emits change event, which should lead to rerender of your root component with the user information you got.

Then, based on the new user roles or permissions in your store, you can have for example ES7 decorator on some of your components deciding, if it displays the actual component or not.

Hope it helps you a bit.